# Combine records with same ID, but different attributes into one record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Lets say for instance I have a table with the following records...

```
ID | Attribute
1      BLUE
1      GREEN
1      RED
2      YELLOW
2      GREEN
3      GREEN
```

I want to condense it into 1 record with all the attributes.

```
ID | Attribute1 | Attribute2 | Attribute3
1      BLUE         GREEN         RED
2      YELLOW       GREEN
3      GREEN
```

I was heading down the path of PIVOT, but don't know how to distinctly insert attributes into separate columns considering they share the same ID/Key. I am using SSMS.

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using ?

Comment: Each `ID` can have maximum of 3 `Attributes` or it is unknown ?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: For the table I am currently working on, the max I have is 3 attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,Row_number()OVER(partition BY [ID] ORDER BY [Attribute]) rn
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT [ID],
       Max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [Attribute] ELSE '' END) AS [Attribute1],
       Max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN [Attribute] ELSE '' END) AS [Attribute2],
       Max(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN [Attribute] ELSE '' END) AS [Attribute3]
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY [ID]
```

In case you want to work with unknown number of attributes then

```
DECLARE @int INT = 1,
        @cnt INT,
        @sql VARCHAR(max)

SELECT TOP 1 @cnt = Count(1)OVER(partition BY [ID])
FROM   Yourtable
ORDER  BY Count(1)OVER(partition BY [ID]) DESC

SET @sql = ';WITH cte
         AS (SELECT *,Row_number()OVER(partition BY [ID] ORDER BY [Attribute]) rn
             FROM   Yourtable)
    SELECT [ID],'

WHILE @int <= @cnt
  BEGIN
      SET @sql += 'Max(CASE WHEN rn = ' + Cast(@int AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' THEN [Attribute] ELSE '''' END) AS [Attribute' + Cast(@int AS VARCHAR(20)) + '],'
      SET @int +=1
  END

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, Len(@sql) - 1)
SET @sql += 'FROM   cte GROUP  BY [ID]' 

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I just threw in NULLs instead of ' '. Appreciate the help! Need to sharpen up a bit on using CTE's.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to go dynamic, a conditional aggregation may help

```
Select ID
      ,max(case when RN=1 then Attribute else '' end)) as Attribute1 
      ,max(case when RN=2 then Attribute else '' end)) as Attribute2 
      ,max(case when RN=3 then Attribute else '' end)) as Attribute3
 From (
        Select *
              ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order By Attribute)
         From YourTable
      )
 Group By ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work and is quite simple to use

```
select * from(
        select 
             ID
            ,Attribute
            ,row_number() over(partition by ID order by Attribute) as AttributeNumber
        from [YourTable]
        group by ID
                ,Attribute
            )t1
PIVOT
(
MAX(Attribute)
FOR AttributeNumber in ([1],[2],[3])-- add more as needed
)piv
```